Effect Coverflow Swiper Js doesn't work properly in tailwind with Laravel 11
How to make the swiperjs coverflow effect work properly on the tailwind project.
I have followed the process to include swiperjs in the project but when implemented into the tailwind project, the image immediately enlarges and is not like the preview on the swiperjs web, what should I do, I think this happens because there is a conflict between tailwind and swiperjs.
I have searched everywhere on the internet but no one discusses it, as well as Ai etc. but still can't find the right solution, I hope someone helps me
Below is my app.css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gloock&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:ital,wght@0,500;1,500&display=swap");

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
    .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
    }

    .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

<div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>

